# Problem with a non-numeric value encountered in php code

Tags: php

Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
$delay_time = $delay_time * 1000;
```

It has to do with the latest version of PHP.

I am running PHP 7.

Comment: Which problem? what `$delay_time` containe?

Answer (score 0):

please check whether $delay_time is a numeric or string

Add this condition in your code

```
if (is_numeric($delay_time)) { 
// Your Code...
}
```